# how to select postgres rows where at least one json element matches some criteria?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-json

Here's what I'm working with:

```
create table test(id INT, data JSON);
INSERT into test values
  (1, '[{"key": 2}, {"key": 1}]'),
  (2, '[{"key": 3}]'),
  (3, '[{"key": 1}]');


select * from test;
select id from test where 1 == ANY( json_array_elements(data) ->> 'key');
```

What I'm trying to do is select all rows where any of the json objects in the `data` column have a key `key` with a value of `1`. I trying to extract rows `1` and `3`. Note, I'm not sure if the equality comparison `==` right before the `ANY` clause is correct.

When I run the above, I get the following error: `ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE`

Comment: Are you bound to the data type `json` or is `jsonb` an option? Is the table big and performance relevant? Please *always* declare your version of Postgres.

Comment: Please refer to this similar question on why ANY doesn't work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675174/querying-data-within-json-array-data-field/21677486#21677486

Comment: in SQL the comparison operator is `=` fix that and it should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are free to use [**`jsonb`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) instead of `json` (which is preferable in most cases), use the [`jsonb` "contains" operator `@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

```
SELECT *
FROM   test
WHERE  data  @> '[{"key": 1"}]';
```

Can be supported with a GIN index with default operator class or with the more specialized `jsonb_path_ops`:

```
CREATE INDEX test_data_gin_idx ON test USING gin (data jsonb_path_ops);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e3d75f0fd77e60afed3d43e80ae0c209)*

Related:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery to accomplish what you want.

```
SELECT test.id
       FROM test
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM json_array_elements(test.data) jar(e)
                            WHERE jar.e->>'key' = '1');
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/47f16/2)